# How to find parent and child type of a type?

Tags: types, julia

```
julia> Integer <: Real
true
```

If we don't know the answer (`Real`) how to find the supertype of `Integer`?

Also, how to find all the subtypes of `Integer`?

Answer (score 12):

```
julia> supertype(Integer)
Real

julia> subtypes(Integer)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 Bool
 Signed
 Unsigned
```

see also https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24741